# Kentico - Content Only page & smart search result

Tags: kentico

I have a custom page types (Content Only) for Locations. Then I have a landing page (/company/locations/) with repeater to list all locations and their details. Things work well so far. Now, after adding the smart search, I notice that if I search a location name like "san francisco", the landing page didn't show up in search result, but the content-only page showed with a URL like this /company/locations/san-francisco. The thing is, this URL results in 404 since that page doesn't really exist. What should I do? Should I re-create the page type and change it to a regular page instead of content only before it's too late? Or is there a way to make individual location url (/company/locations/san-francisco) work - considering we can't specify a page template to go with content only page type? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want that URL to show then simply exclude those page types from that search index.  But if you want them to specifically show, then create a detail or selected transformation for that `/company/locations` repeater to display when someone navigates to it from the search.  This will also be good for google and other search indexes if you plan to have specifics for each location.

Comment: I've tried 2 things. [1] excluded the page type from search, which is not good since searching for "san francisco" won't give any results (the landing with the repeater doesn't show in result either) and [2] I did added an item transformation in the first place but the individual url doesn't display anything. From your response, I guess maybe I got something wrong along the way...

Comment: You need to add a selected item transformation not an item.  The item is a listing and not a specifically selected one.

Comment: Thanks. (I meant "selected item transformation" in my comment above :) ) But anyway I had to re-create my custom page type - changing it from content-only page type to a regular page type, and things worked well as expected. Wasted some time re-doing it. Although my problem is solved, the remaining question I want to know the answer is whether we can display content-only page as a regular page. The documentation on Kentico about content-only is a little unclear when it mentioned using url pattern to display content - I tried and it didn't work, so don't know if it's me or the system.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple types of Search indexes in Kentico.

"Pages" scans the data of a document, such as any webparts+properties, editable text, form data, etc. They do NOT scan the rendering on the page though, it doesn't catch any Repeaters (what you're using).

"Page Crawler" will literally load the page, and scan all the content in the page.  This will catch Repeaters and dynamic content like that.

Knowing this, you have a couple options.

1. Use Pages, then Modify the Smart Search Result and add some transformation logic to say something like the below

```html
<a href="<% IfCompare(GetSearchValue("ClassName"), "custom.Location", "/company/locations", SearchResultUrl())%>">The Link</a>
```

2. Use Page Crawler, tell it specifically to only index the /company/locations.
3. Use Page Crawler, and also a custom smart search indexer so you can exclude the header/footer or other areas out of the content (it's a bit more advanced)

Comment: Thanks for the page crawler bit - I didn't know that even exists